# ASP.NET MVC, Cross-Area Routing, ActionResults, and Implications on Design

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I remember when ASP.NET MVC was new, there was a lot of contention over the concept of the popular `Html.ActionResult<T>` that was available in MvcFutures because it 'violated separation of concerns'.

The way I understand it is that if something is not native to the controller, it should not really be called by a View. And so it is considered 'bad' practice to call something from another Controller.

This is both understandable, and problematic. From the perspective of the intention of design, I understand this philosophy - I also understand that this has been debated until people are blue in the face, so I've no intention of *arguing* with anyone. I just want opinions. Given the following layout, I'm wondering if I am in too much violation of the principle concept of ASP.NET MVC.

To explain it in better terms, A `Member` has an `IList<Character>` property. So one `Member` has multiple `Characters`. The structure below basically establishes an *area* for `Member` to look at their own data, as well as Manage, Create, and Select a `Character` -  but the actual control and manipulation of `Character` is kept inside of the `Character` area.

Why am I afraid this is bad? Well, because I'm a young, naive programmer who is excited that I got what I want to do to work, and I have learned from experience that building something good from the start is better than building something that works, incorrectly.

The problem I see is that my `Member` area seems to be 'aware' of my `Character` area, and the model. (`Character` and `Member` both are Models defined in an external `Models.dll` library that has nothing to do with ASP.NET MVC. I am using `Castle.Windsor` as my IoC container, and `Fluent nHibernate` as my ORM.

`ICharacterRepository` handles creating Characters. `IMemberRepository` handles retrieving members based on the Authentication (drawn from `HttpContext.User.Identity`).

### Too Long, Didn't Read

> Can some more experienced programmers tell me if my approach is just flawed, or if I am taking even remotely right steps? And if it is wrong, can you offer any alternatives? I feel my folder structure has become quite large, and while it does make sense to me, I have read that the goal of MVC is 'simplicity'. I wish to know if I have made this too complicated, or if even 'simple' projects can start to get pretty complex.

```
/Areas
 /Character
   /Controllers
     /HomeController(ICharacterRepository, IMemberRepository)
       - ViewResult Index(int id)
   /Views
     /Home
       - Index
 /Member
   /Controllers
     /HomeController(ICharacterRepository,IMemberRepository)
     - Characters()
     /CharacterController(ICharacterRepository,IMemberRepository)
     - JsonResult Select(int id)
     - ViewResult Create(string name)
   /Views
     /Home
       - Characters
     /Character
       - Create
       - Select (Partial)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see a problem with the structure you have above, but it honestly comes down to what you are intending to do.

There is no problem exposing your `Character` class to your `MemberController` if the functionality is required to do so, and if you require a `CharacterController` in your `Member` area then that can be perfectly valid.

If you start doubling up functionality of a `CharacterController` in both `Member` and `Character` areas then the structure should be revised.

In regards to:

> The way I understand it is that if
>   something is not native to the
>   controller, it should not really be
>   called by a View. And so it is
>   considered 'bad' practice to call
>   something from another Controller.

I would agree to an extent, yes, primarily my main view's model would be exposed via it's controller, but in certain cases you may wish to call upon a Helper or Utility class or extension methods right from within your view if required.  However if you are stating should you be doing `<%:CharacterController.PrintSomething %>` within your `MemberController` view, no you shouldn't be.  Whatever it is you wish to access should have been provided in your view model from the requesting controller's action.

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 1):

One controller per model class is the default, but it really only works for pure CRUD pages. A lot of the time that is what you need, so it makes sense as a default, but for anything more complex your structure will be dictated by what the user expects rather than your data model.

From a user perspective there is nothing wrong with a page/action that has both a member and a character on it, or being able to create a character in more than one place, and that's what your controller needs to accomodate. Seperation of concerns is applied at the next level up - You only get into trouble if you have things like MemberRepository writing characters, potentially in a different way to CharacterRepository. Also, with everything strongly typed it is easy to find references to a particular class even if they are scattered through the project.

You may also want to look at my answer on model design [asp.mvc model design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4595539/asp-mvc-model-design/4599825#4599825) - the mapping from form/model class to data object can be fairly indirect.